# Failed Database to add Data

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a CRUD Application using .Net Core Api with Angular11.I follow this link  https://www.codaffection.com/asp-net-core-article/angular-crud-with-asp-net-core-web-api/   for creating this.and I not totally completed all functionality yet.just i created functionality 'Add from information into the database.'But when I click the "Submit" button to add my form data into the database, then I have seen an unexpected situation.also, data could not add to my DB.

Here is my code:-

`Backend`

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using PaymentApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PaymentApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        //other code

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "PaymentApi", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddDbContext<PaymentDetailContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));

            services.AddCors();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(options=>options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            );

            //other code
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PaymentApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PaymentApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PaymentDetailController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly PaymentDetailContext _context;

        public PaymentDetailController(PaymentDetailContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/PaymentDetail
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PaymentDetails>>> GetPaymentDetails()
        {
            return await _context.PaymentDetails.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/PaymentDetail/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PaymentDetails>> GetPaymentDetail(int id)
        {
            var paymentDetail = await _context.PaymentDetails.FindAsync(id);

            if (paymentDetail == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return paymentDetail;
        }

        // PUT: api/PaymentDetail/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutPaymentDetail(int id, PaymentDetails paymentDetail)
        {
            if (id != paymentDetail.PaymentDetailId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(paymentDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PaymentDetailExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/PaymentDetail
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PaymentDetails>> PostPaymentDetail(PaymentDetails paymentDetail)
        {
            _context.PaymentDetails.Add(paymentDetail);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPaymentDetail", new { id = paymentDetail.PaymentDetailId }, paymentDetail);
        }

        // DELETE: api/PaymentDetail/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePaymentDetail(int id)
        {
            var paymentDetail = await _context.PaymentDetails.FindAsync(id);
            if (paymentDetail == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.PaymentDetails.Remove(paymentDetail);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool PaymentDetailExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.PaymentDetails.Any(e => e.PaymentDetailId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

`Frontend`

Payment-Details.model.ts

```
export class PaymentDetails {

    paymentDetailId: number=0;
    cardOwnerName: string='';
    cardNumber: string='';
    expirationDate: string='';
    securityCode: string='';
}
```

PaymentDetails.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PaymentDetails } from './payment-details.model';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaymentDetailsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:55235/api/PaymentDetail'
  formData: PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetails();
  list: PaymentDetails[];

  postPaymentDetail() {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, this.formData);
  }

  putPaymentDetail() {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseURL}/${this.formData.paymentDetailId}`, this.formData);
  }

  deletePaymentDetail(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`);
  }

  refreshList() {
    this.http.get(this.baseURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res =>this.list = res as PaymentDetails[]);
  }


}
```

payment-details-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{PaymentDetailsService}from 'src/app/shared/payment-details.service'
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { PaymentDetails } from 'src/app/shared/payment-details.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-details-form',
  templateUrl: './payment-details-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-details-form.component.css']
})
export class PaymentDetailsFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service:PaymentDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm)
  {
         this.service.postPaymentDetail().subscribe(
          
          res=>{

          },

          err=>{
            console.log(err);
          }

         );

  }

}
```

payment-details-form.component.html

```
<form novalidate  #form="ngForm"  (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentDetailId"
    [value]="service.formData.paymentDetailId" />

  <div class="from-group">
      <label >CARD OWNER NAME</label>
      <input  class="form-control from-control-lg" placeholder="FULL NAME"
      name="cardOwnerName" #cardOwnerName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.cardOwnerName"
        required [class.invalid]="cardOwnerName.invalid && cardOwnerName.touched"/>
  </div>

  <div class="from-group">
    <label >CARD NUMBER</label>
    <input  class="form-control from-control-lg" placeholder="16 DIGIT CARD NUMBER"
    name="cardNumber" #cardNumber="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.cardNumber"
     required maxlength="8" minlength="2" [class.invalid]="cardNumber.invalid && cardNumber.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="from-group col-md-6">
    <label >SECURITY CODE</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control from-control-lg" placeholder="SECURITY CODE"
    name="securityCode" #securityCode="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.securityCode"
    required maxlength="8" minlength="2" [class.invalid]="securityCode.invalid && securityCode.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="from-group col-md-6">
    <label >VALID THROUGH</label>
    <input   class="form-control from-control-lg" placeholder="MM/YY"
    name="expirationDate" #expirationDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.expirationDate"
    required [class.invalid]="expirationDate.invalid && expirationDate.touched"/>
</div>

</div>
<br/>
<div class="form-group">

 <button class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block;" type="submit" [disabled]=form.invalid >SUBMIT</button>

</div>
</form>
```

When I run my angular project to add my form data into my DB then I found this error.

[image]

when I click submit button to add my data to the database. then I found these errors.I am an absolute beginner. please help.

this is I found visual studio output.

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:55235/" for site "PaymentApi" application "/"
Registration completed for site "PaymentApi"
IIS Express is running.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\fullstack\PaymentApi\PaymentApi
Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. The recommended protocol version is TLS 1.2 and later.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1,549ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 16), @p1='?' (Size = 100), @p2='?' (Size = 5), @p3='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [PaymentDetails] ([CardNumber], [CardOwnerName], [ExpirationDate], [SecurityCode])
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);
      SELECT [PaymentDetailId]
      FROM [PaymentDetails]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [PaymentDetailId] = scope_identity();
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'PaymentApi.Models.PaymentDetailContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
      The statement has been terminated.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      ClientConnectionId:123b0a93-424e-4068-a878-2db210cfdc91
      Error Number:8152,State:13,Class:16
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
      The statement has been terminated.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      ClientConnectionId:123b0a93-424e-4068-a878-2db210cfdc91
      Error Number:8152,State:13,Class:16
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
      The statement has been terminated.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      ClientConnectionId:123b0a93-424e-4068-a878-2db210cfdc91
      Error Number:8152,State:13,Class:16
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at PaymentApi.Controllers.PaymentDetailController.PostPaymentDetail(PaymentDetails paymentDetail) in C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\fullstack\PaymentApi\PaymentApi\Controllers\PaymentDetailController.cs:line 81
         at lambda_method6(Closure , Object )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: You've got too much going on here in your question. You need to narrow it down to the section of code that's actually giving you an issue, please review [mcve].

Comment: @mason The problem is why I have found this issue I did not understand.and this code is so simple,just i create a functionality" add data to DB" I used here Angular and .Net core web API. so for that you seen a lot of code.

Comment: You need to follow the guidelines of [mcve] still. Just dumping all your code on us after not understanding where the issue is - that's not acceptable.

Comment: At least you should try to copy the stack trace of the exception into the question. :) If you switch from the IIS profile to Kestrel, near the run button, you'll most likely be able to see the exception being logged into the console window that opens.

Comment: Please check the `output` panel in visual studio and share the detailed error message to us.

Comment: @Rena I did update my question. I posted here the visual studio output. please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the exception message: `"String or binary data would be truncated."`. That means that you're trying to store a string that's larger than the database field's width. Look at the widths of the database fields and see which one is shorter than the string you're entering.

Answer (score 0):

services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
try adding this after addcors

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).